# Express the following as a finite sum of complex exponentials

Tags: complex-numbers

Given Euler's formula $e^{jx}=\cos(x)+j\sin(x)$ ($j$ is the imaginary number), could I know how to write the following $f(x)$ as a finite sum of complex exponentials:

1)$$f(t)=1+\cos(t)+\sin(2t+90^{\circ})$$
2)$$f(t)=\cos^2(2t)+\sin(3t)$$

I know that $cos(t)\cdot$length is basically the vector's $"x"$ value, and $sin(x)\cdot$length is basically the vector's $"y"$ value. So you can convert a polar expression into a rectangular expression. But how could I convert those $cos$ and $sin$ into the sum of complex exponentials? And is $1$ can be viewed as $e^{j\cdot0}$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: $\,e^{-jx}=\cos(x)-j \sin(x)\,$, so $\cos x = (e^{jx}+e^{-jx})/2\,$, and similarly $\ldots$

Comment: @dxiv Got it. So by using this we can find out the complex exponential of $cos$ to be $\frac{1}{2}e^{jx}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-jx}$ right? I am not sure whether it's ok to have coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$ before $e$.

Comment: Right. As for `not sure whether it's ok to have coefficient` those coefficients are part of the identity, and it just won't work without them.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks a lot!